# Google Chart API: how can I change the format of dates on an axis?

Tags: google-visualization

I have a google chart (set up using [chartkick](http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/) And I am trying to make the dates appear shorter on the chart. My Data set looks something like this:

```
{"03/01/13" : 3, "03/02/13" : 0, "03/03/13" : 10 }  //etc.
```

However, when I load up the chart the date is formatted like so:  Mar 1, 2013.
How can I get the date to appear as I passed it, or in some other short format? The longer fields looked very cramped on the page I am using it on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's happening now is that the chart takes your string, parses it to a Javascript Date object, and then uses the chart's default display options to show the date.

According to the [Google Charts Docs](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options), you can pass an option `format` to the axes using the [ICU Pattern Set](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details). So for example, you would specify `hAxis.format = "MM/dd/yy"` to get `"03/03/13"`.

Using Chartkick, you should be able to use the `:library` syntax to pass [options](http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/#options).

Comment: Note this only works for continuous charts such as line_chart, not discreet charts such as bar_chart or column_chart

Comment: one thing i'ved found out is that passing in dd/mm/yy as data values will always intepret as mm/dd/yy. there is no way i'ved found out to change the date formatting rule. But you are right on hAxis display format. Is there a way to change the date input format rule ?

Comment: Chartkick accepts multi-nested hash for library option. For the date-format change the hash would look something like: `library: {'hAxis' => {'format' => 'MM/dd/yy'}`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.Use this line inside the options.

```
var options = {
               format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
              }
```

Take a look at this for the working sample. [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-divide-horizontal-axis-of-line-chart-in-weekly-intervals/)

Comment: just a heads up, the link you sent me has a 500 internal error message.

Comment: just checked again, seems fine now. Must have been a temporary error